# Penney Game - mapping macros to strings

Tags: c, strings, game, programming-challenge, macros

[The SPOJ problem](http://www.spoj.com/problems/NY10A/):

> Given a 40 character string representing outcomes of 40 coin tosses,
>   find the frequency destribution of all the possible outcome triplets.
>   So, for string like : HHHH....40 Hs ,the result is HHH : 38 and the
>   rest 0. The exact input output format is given in the link.

My approach, as is clear from the code, is to iterate through the string and match all consecutive sub-strings of length 3, while increasing the frequency count.

My solution got accepted, but I am not really happy with what I have done here. As you can see, there is a lot of redundant code I could not remove.

For instance, if string "TTT" could be directly mapped to the macro TTT, somehow, and so on, a large number of lines of code could have been reduced. I know technically strings and macros are two different things, but is there some trick that I am missing?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<limits.h>
#define TTT 0
#define TTH 1
#define THT 2
#define THH 3
#define HTT 4
#define HTH 5
#define HHT 6
#define HHH 7
void getCount(char str[] , int count[]){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<8;++i)
        count[i]=0;

    int l = strlen(str);
    for(i=2;i<l;++i){
        if(strncmp(str+i-2 , "TTT" , 3)==0)
            ++count[TTT];
        if(strncmp(str+i-2 , "TTH" , 3)==0)
            ++count[TTH];
        if(strncmp(str+i-2 , "THT" , 3)==0)
            ++count[THT];
        if(strncmp(str+i-2 , "THH" , 3)==0)
            ++count[THH];
        if(strncmp(str+i-2 , "HTT" , 3)==0)
            ++count[HTT];
        if(strncmp(str+i-2 , "HTH" , 3)==0)
            ++count[HTH];
        if(strncmp(str+i-2 , "HHT" , 3)==0)
            ++count[HHT];
        if(strncmp(str+i-2 , "HHH" , 3)==0)
            ++count[HHH];
    }
}
int main()
{
    char str[41];
    int t,n,count[8],i;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--){
        scanf("%d",&n);
        printf("%d ",n);

        scanf("%s",str);
        getCount(str,count);

        for(i=0;i<8;++i){
            printf("%d ",count[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please give details about the problem rather than posting where's described.
We would also appreciate if you told us how you decided to solve it.

Comment: The problem is: given a 40 character string representing outcomes of 40 coin tosses, find the frequency destribution of all the possible outcome triplets. So, for string like : HHHH....40 Hs ,the result is HHH : 38 and the rest 0. The exact input output format is given in the link.

Comment: My approach : as is clear from the code, iterate through the string and match all consecutive sub-strings of length 3, while increasing the frequency count

Comment: In the main post, so that there's no need to go through comments to find out it.

Answer (score 4):

Associating a set of constants with corresponding strings is difficult in C.  One approach is to define a structure, such as

```
struct patterns {
    const char combination[4];
    int count;
};
```

Here we have space for a string and an integer to count occurrences.
Creating an array of these and initializing it gives us this:

```
struct patterns patterns[N_PATTERNS] = {
    {"HHH", 0}, {"HHT", 0}, {"HTH", 0}, {"HTT", 0},
    {"THH", 0}, {"THT", 0}, {"TTH", 0}, {"TTT", 0},
};
```

Then you can loop through the strings by accessing each array member and
incrementing the counts.  The count and string are kept together so that
indexing errors cannot happen.

Also, your `main` is too complicated.  Just reading the string from the
command line is easier.

Putting it together, gives me this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N_PATTERNS 8
struct patterns {
    const char combination[4];
    int count;
};

static int increment_occurance(struct patterns *p, const char *s)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N_PATTERNS; ++i) {
        if (!memcmp(s, p[i].combination, 3)) {
            p[i].count += 1;
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

static void count_occurances(struct patterns *p, const char *s)
{
    const char *end = s + strlen(s) - 2;

    for (; s < end; ++s) {
        increment_occurance(p, s);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct patterns patterns[N_PATTERNS] = {
        {"HHH", 0}, {"HHT", 0}, {"HTH", 0}, {"HTT", 0},
        {"THH", 0}, {"THT", 0}, {"TTH", 0}, {"TTT", 0},
    };
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s string\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    count_occurances(patterns, argv[1]);

    for (int i = 0; i < N_PATTERNS; ++i) {
        printf("%s %d\n", patterns[i].combination, patterns[i].count);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

EDIT: note that we can use the more efficient `memcmp` instead of `strncmp` in `increment_occurance`.

Comment: Could you cite a source that points to `memcmp()` being more efficient than `strncmp()`?

Comment: @syb0rg `memcmp` is going to check char pairs only for equivalence, whereas `strncmp`  must also check each char against `\0`. Having said that, I don't really like the embedded length (3) so I'm not sure that was good advice - and the efficiency difference will be trivial.

Answer (score 3):

### Style

- **Variable names**: it's ok naming variables with a meaningless one character **if and only if** that program will not be read from another human.
  Otherwise just don't: use proper names, that will help both you and future readers.
- **Take out headers you don't use**: I haven't seen any function which belongs to
  `stdlib and limit` being used.
- **Spaces**: Do not underestimate them. They are very useful to make the code cleaner. Moreover, the have no drawback: compilers ignore them.
- **Messages**: Warn the user about what kind of input you are actually waiting for.

---

### Code

- I have noticed an attempt to avoid unsafe functions with `strncmp`, but the issue is located before you compare them. That is, when you **acquire** them.
  Although `scanf` can be used for strings, and in this case it is the right choice, it can easily overflow the buffer that's filling.
  Format the string so:`%(character_to_read)s` in order to prevent buffer overflows.
  I'd use it rather than `fgets` becase `fgets` reads spaces as well, which we would have to get rid from later.
- You can declare a variable inside the `for` loop since C99.

---

### Optimization

An associative container would be the best option. The website doesn't have any constraints about the language: C does not have any associative container (or hash table) in its stdlib, while C++ does.

A lookup table (string -> array index) is likely faster than `strncmp`ing, but I wouldn't recommend it unless needed, especially if you have to implement it from scratch. There might be other dark tricks though.

Answer (score 2):

You could start by replacing the `#define`s with an `enum`:

```
typedef enum { TTT, TTH, THT, THH, HTT, HTH, HHT, HHH } Combination;
```

As for mapping strings to macros, I suppose this could work with a `toString()` function.  It could have a `switch` statement that receives an `enum` value and returns its associated string.  This may not be too concise, but C doesn't give you very many concise options.

Comment: I was thinking of a more general solution. So, that I could keep adding macros in a header file and without changing the c code, access the macros through strings.

Comment: @user43115: That may become messy, and I'm not sure if online challenges involve having multiple files.  You may just need to try for something within one file.

Comment: I was just curious as I remember having to write over a 100 lines of code in a compilers course assignment in a similar scenario. I did not have the exact statement of that so, I used this problem statement instead.

Comment: Also, how does using enum guarantee that the actual int values of TTT ,..,HHH will be in the range [0,8). I could have other enum types in the program as well.

Comment: @user43115: The numerical range may be specified somewhere in the C standard (there *may* be some compilers that use a different range, but `enum`s almost always start at 0).  It has also been stated that [`enum`s are preferred over `#define`s](http://users.ece.cmu.edu/~eno/coding/CCodingStandard.html#useenums).